# How to rearrange not diagonally dominant matrices to diagonally dominant matrices?

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods

I have an extended matrix:
$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    78 & 53 & 48 & 18 \\
    33 & 11 & 18 & 23 \\
    45 & 33 & 28 & 34 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
I need to rearrange it to [Diagonally dominant matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonally_dominant_matrix), to use [Iterative method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_method).
"Diagonally dominant matrix" means:
$$ |a_{ii}| > \sum_{j=0, j\neq i}^n |a_{ij}| .  i=1..n $$
Could anyone help me ?
My try:
$R_1 \rightarrow R_1 + 10*R_2$
$R_2 \rightarrow R_1 - 2*R_2$
$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    408 & 163 & 228 & 248 \\
    12 & 31 & 12 & -28 \\
    ? & ? & ? & ? \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
But as you can see, I'm stuck on the 3rd row. I have no idea what else I can do.

Comment: "I need to bring it to "Diagonally dominant matrix", to use Iterative method." ==> Can you elaborate on this ?

Comment: @G.Fougeron what of this is not clear to you ?

Comment: what does "to bring a matrix" mean ?

Comment: @G.Fougeron I think, incorrect translation. "Rearrange", I think it will suit more.

Comment: Are you sure you need to rearrange? Having a diagonally dominant matrix is just a sufficient condition for the convergence of Jacobi or Gauss-Seidel's methods, it is not a necessary condition.

Comment: @PierreCarre, I think yes. Because that's how my task sounds: "Привести систему к виду, пригодному для итераций". (Rearrange the system to a form suitable for iterations)

Comment: @PierreCarre ... and when I tried to solve this system by the Jacobi method (using Wikipedia Python code), the solution diverges. But "Gaussian elimination" gives me an answer.